# Unable to create table in SQL Server Express 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2017 Express Edition.

Then I start the server with `sqlcmd -S myPC\SQLEXPRESS02 -E`.

Running the following Python code, I got no errors:

```
import pyodbc

connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};" \
                     "server=myPC\SQLEXPRESS02;" \
                     "Trusted_Connection=Yes;" \
                     "database=mydb;" \
                     "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" \
                     "connection timeout=30"

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cur = conn.cursor()

cmd = 'CREATE TABLE myTable(ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, Text char(5) NOT NULL, title NVARCHAR(MAX))'
cur.execute(cmd)
cur.close()
```

After that, I reconnect the db using the same connection string. When I executed the command `select * from myTable`, the following error appeared

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'myTable'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Anything wrong with my connection and command? Did I miss somethings? How to solve the problem?

Comment: You can't create NOT NULL column directly while creating a table.

    CREATE TABLE myTable(ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, Text char(5) NOT NULL, title NVARCHAR(MAX))

In addition to this Text is a keyword in SQL Server. Try renameing Text Column.

Comment: But I can create `myTable` in MS SQL Management Studio using the same SQL query.

Comment: do you get any exception . try exception handling in the above code. so that i can help